# Export .ipa file from Xcode project without ever opening Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

We have an API that users can call to create Cordova apps/projects, upload their www directory, and then start compilation and download the executable binary file. This binary file will then go into a private app store.

I'm having trouble with the compile step for iOS. The Cordova build step is no problem, but it doesn't output a binary file, like it does for Android. After reading everything I found on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, the plan was this:

```
xcodebuild clean -configuration Release -alltargets
xcodebuild -scheme MyApp archive -archivePath build/MyApp
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "build/MyApp.xcarchive" -exportPath "MyApp.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "My Prov Profile"
```

Given that the signing identity and everything is set up correctly, it almost works. The first command executes fine. The second command just hangs.

However, if I open the project in Xcode, and then execute the commands, it compiles and exports, and I'm left with an .ipa file, which is what I wanted. It seems that Xcode sets up a workspace and some scheme-related things when the project is first opened.

Is there any way I can get xcodebuild (or xcrun, or anything, for that matter) to create this workspace file for me?

Or is there another way to approach this?

Right now, I have a solution where I actually open the Xcode project, wait 15 seconds, and then proceed. But I can think of a thousand ways that will fail at some point, so I would like to change it to something a little more elegant.

I currently have Xcode 6.3 installed, if that is relevant.

---

Update: Opal's answer below set me on the right path (I think). What I ended up doing, was exporting a shared scheme as per Opal's link, and using that as a template for future apps. The solutions was something like this:

```
# Copy shared scheme file into directory
mkdir /path/to/project/dir/MyApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata
mkdir /path/to/project/dir/MyApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes
cp data/MyScheme.xcscheme /path/to/project/dir/MyApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/.

# Use sed to replace app name in scheme file
sed -i '' "s/%app_name%/MyApp/g" MyApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/MyScheme.xcscheme

# CD into directory
cd /path/to/project/dir

# Move files from Cordova to our build directory
cp -r CordovaLib/build/* build/.

# Build and export
xcodebuild clean -configuration Release -alltargets
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme archive -archivePath build/MyApp
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "build/MyApp.xcarchive" -exportPath "MyApp.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "MyProvProfile"
```

Comment: It seem that schemes in your project are not shared and xcode creates them after opening the project. You need shared schemes.

Comment: @Opal OK. How do I go about setting up shared schemes?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/facebook/xctool in README section.

Comment: Let me know if it does change anything.

Comment: @Opal This seems to work, thanks! What I ended up doing, was adding a generic scheme file to my system, where I replaced some strings to get the app name correct and so on.

Comment: Will add in as an answer, please accept if it helped you.

Comment: I will add my actual solution as a separate answer, but I want to check out @kumar's answer below first. That might also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the application you try to build has no shared schemes. Schemes if not shared, are created when project is loaded to xcode. To create shared schemes see [this](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) site.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I used to automate ipa generation without opening xcode in my cordova environment. (xcode version: 6.0.1 cordova version: 3.6.0)

- Change in **cordova/build.xcconfig**: **CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Distribution**  (change "Developer" to "Distribution".  )
- run `cordova build ios --device` in cordova workspace that generates .app file
- Sign using : `xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v ${WORKSPACE}/platforms/ios/build/device/${application.name}.app -o ${WORKSPACE}/platforms/ios/build/${application.name}.ipa --embed ${ios.distribution.provisionfile}.mobileprovision --sign ${code.signing.identity}`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me, I get an error saying first "Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!", and then "/var/folders/8l/l22zrl_n2v34qfxzwfpbdjxc0000gn/T/wh4epkuky9/Payload/TestMac.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources".

Comment: Oh Ok! am using OS X 10.9.5. I will update and try to fix the issue.Thanks for your update.